# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

Tags: java, exception, encoding

Hi i am developping an Email Filter for an application that scan through mails to determine if they are or not spams, here is my class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import ca.etsmtl.logti.log619.lab05.utilities.EmailSplicer;

public class MotsClesFilter implements EmailFilter {

    final String NAME = "Filtrage par mots cles";
    private Pattern chaineSpam;
    private Matcher chaineCourriel;
    private int nbOccMotSpam =0;
    private byte confidenceLevel;
    @Override
    public String getFilterName() {
        return this.NAME;

    }

    @Override
    public byte checkSpam(MimeMessage message) {
        analyze(message);
        switch(this.nbOccMotSpam){
        case 0:
            this.confidenceLevel = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            this.confidenceLevel = CANT_SAY;
            break;
        case 2:
            this.confidenceLevel= 50;
            break;
        case 3:
            this.confidenceLevel = 70;
            break;
        case 4 :
            this.confidenceLevel = 80;
            break;



        } return (getConfidenceLevel());
    }


    public void analyze(MimeMessage message){
        try {
            List<String> listeChaines = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("SpamWords.txt"))));
            while(bis.ready()){
                String ligne = bis.readLine();
                listeChaines.add(ligne);
            }
            String[] tabMots = EmailSplicer.getMessageContent(message);
            for (int i =0;i<tabMots.length;i++){
                /*System.out.print("*************************************");
                System.out.print(tabMots[0]);
                System.out.print("**************************************");*/
                for (int j =0; j<listeChaines.size();j++){
                    this.chaineSpam = Pattern.compile(listeChaines.get(j));
                    this.chaineCourriel = this.chaineSpam.matcher(tabMots[i]);
                    if (this.chaineCourriel.matches())
                        this.nbOccMotSpam++;

                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public byte getConfidenceLevel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.confidenceLevel;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here's the EmailSplicer utility class that i am using:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 * Utility class to return all the content of a MimeMessage
 * @author Maxime Caumartin <maxime.caumartin.1@ens.etsmtl.ca>
 */
public class EmailSplicer {

    /**
     * Contains the types of email parts that can be analyzed by this class.
     * @author Maxime Caumartin <maxime.caumartin.1@ens.etsmtl.ca>
     */
    private enum ContentTypes
    {
        Plain("text/plain"), HTML("text/html"), Multipart("multipart"), Unknown(
                "?");

        private String  type;

        ContentTypes(String type)
        {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public static ContentTypes getType(String type)
        {
            if (type.contains(Plain.type))
                return Plain;
            if (type.contains(HTML.type))
                return HTML;
            if (type.contains(Multipart.type))
                return Multipart;
            return Unknown;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Recursive method that passes through all the parts of the Mutlipart message and returns an ArrayList<String> of the content of these parts.
     * @param multiPartMsg The Multipart that needs to be dissected.
     * @return The ArrayList<String> containing all the content of the Mutlipart message.
     * @throws MessagingException Exception thrown if the analyzer cannot read the message.
     * @throws IOException Exception thrown if the encoding type isn't valid.
     */
    private static ArrayList<String> getMutlipartContent(Multipart multiPartMsg)
            throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> returnTable = new ArrayList<String>(
                multiPartMsg.getCount());

        for (int i = 0; i < multiPartMsg.getCount(); i++)
        {
            switch (ContentTypes.getType(multiPartMsg.getBodyPart(i)
                    .getContentType()))
            {
                case Plain:
                    returnTable.add((String) multiPartMsg.getBodyPart(i)
                            .getContent());
                    break;
                case HTML:
                    String s = org.clapper.util.html.HTMLUtil.textFromHTML((String) multiPartMsg.getBodyPart(i)
                            .getContent()).trim();
                    if (s.length() != 0)
                        returnTable.add(s);
                    break;
                case Multipart:
                    returnTable
                            .addAll(getMutlipartContent((Multipart) multiPartMsg
                                    .getBodyPart(i).getContent()));
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
        return returnTable;
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the content of the MimeMessage passed as a parameter. The whole content will be parsed.
     * @param message The MimeMessage containing textual information.
     * @return The array of string containing all the strings from the content of the message.
     * @throws MessagingException Exception thrown if the analyzer cannot read the message.
     * @throws IOException Exception thrown if the encoding type isn't valid.
     */
    public static String[] getMessageContent(MimeMessage message)
            throws MessagingException, IOException
    {
        String contentType = message.getContentType();

        switch (ContentTypes.getType(contentType))
        {
            case Plain:
                return new String[] { (String) message.getContent() };
            case Multipart:
                return getMutlipartContent(
                        (Multipart) message.getContent()).toArray(new String[0]);
            case HTML:
                String s = org.clapper.util.html.HTMLUtil.textFromHTML((String) message
                        .getContent()).trim();
                if (s.length() != 0)
                    return new String[] {s};
            default:
                return new String[0];
        }

    }

}
```

Now when i am executing the main method of the whole app, this the exception that i am getting:

```
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: iso-0621-9
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:82)
at javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(Unknown Source)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(Unknown Source)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.getContent(MimeBodyPart.java:629)
at ca.etsmtl.logti.log619.lab05.utilities.EmailSplicer.getMutlipartContent(EmailSplicer.java:69)
at ca.etsmtl.logti.log619.lab05.utilities.EmailSplicer.getMessageContent(EmailSplicer.java:101)
at ca.etsmtl.logti.log619.lab05.filter.MotsClesFilter.analyze(MotsClesFilter.java:66)
at ca.etsmtl.logti.log619.lab05.filter.MotsClesFilter.checkSpam(MotsClesFilter.java:34)
at ca.etsmtl.logti.log619.lab05.Application.main(Application.java:107)
```

Can someone enlighten me on how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

[This document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) lists the supported encodings by Java.

iso-0621-9 is not in the list.

Comment: Link seems to be broken, but here is the 1.6 equivalent: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

Answer (score 2):

ISO-0621-9 is not an encoding, and if it were it is not one that is [supported by Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html). I'd guess this might even be a good indicator of spam: no valid encoding => spam.

A little googling for *ISO 621* shows that [ISO-621](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=4741) is the internation standard for *"Manganese ores -- Determination of metallic iron content (metallic iron content not exceeding 2 %) -- Sulphosalicylic acid photometric method"*

I'd say that has little to do with computers and even less with encodings ;)

Comment: Where in email splicer can i t catch the exception ?

Comment: That depends on how you want handle it. `EmailSplicer` might not  even be the right place.